# Sign google Oauth with defference account in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm using api chrome.identity develop Oauth login.I have a problem when I'm remove token key in cache chrome.When I'm login the first time and then logout out account,It's still using old token key that I'm login in the first time so that I can not login with another google's account.Event if I also clear all cache browser,It still problem with the first account.

Ex :When Google Oauth ask login I'm using account A and then logout account A.And then I'm click button login by Google Oauth but It still using account A,so I can not login account B.(Only I'm uninstall chrome and install new chrome and then I can login another account).
This is my code to remove google token key.How can I fix it.

```
function removeToken() {
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': false },
function (current_token) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        gToken = current_token;
        if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: current_token },
              function () { });
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
                     gToken);
            xhr.send();
        }
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

chrome identity uses the login account from the chrome account, not the one you used to log into the web page. to use with another account use a separate chrome account

Comment: But event if I'm logout chrome account or delete all browser's cache I also can not login another account.You can reference problem in this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/identity-api-sample/oficlfehfenioickohognhdhmmcpceil

Comment: thats not how you login to another account. You create a new chrome account. I use identity api in my published extension as well.